# JSON Mapping any inner objects using Mantle

Tags: objective-c, json, mapping, github-mantle

If I am getting a response like this

```
{
    "objects" : [
          {
              "a" : val1,
              "b" : val2,
          },
          {
              "a" : val1,
              "b" : val2,
          }
     ]
}
```

Then how do get the objects array in the response?

The solutions that I have found are as follows:

1) I can create a model class objectsResponse representing the above json and it will have an NSArray property called objects. And then I can use

> mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass

to map the json response with the objects property and then access the error using objectsResponse's object.

2) Directly use the method

> [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass: [Object fromJsonArray:[response
>   objectForKey:@"objects"]]] error:&error]

Is there any direct way using mantle object mapping other than these?

Thanks